# What's the benefit of using embedded Objectify class?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

Does anyone know the benefit of using **embedded class** in Objectify?  So far, my biggest problem with the embedded class is that I can't access outside of the entity or out of the App Engine Endpoint class.  Just wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using embedded entities saves you from making additional calls to the Datastore.

For example, you may store users' phone numbers as embedded entities in a User entity. This is a good option if you always need phone numbers when you retrieve users. This way if your query returns 100 user entities, you don't have to make 100+ calls to the Datastore to retrieve their phone numbers.

However, if you need to access these numbers separately, or be able search by phone number, a better option is to keep them as separate entities.

Comment: @Andrei...are you talking "embedded entity" or "embedded class?"  They are different.  My question is regarding embedded class.  :)

Comment: Different???  From the documentation: `Any class which is not recognized as a core value type or a special Objectify type will be broken down into its component fields and stored natively as an EmbeddedEntity... Embedded classes are treated just like entities...`

Comment: In other words, the only purpose of EmbeddedClass is to become EmbeddedEntity when it is stored in  the Datastore.